# Converting int to Unicode char in a backwards compatible way

Tags: python, string, unicode, int, backwards-compatibility

Is there a way to convert an int representing a Unicode code point to a Unicode character (string) in Python, where the same conversion code can run in both Python3+ and Python 2.7.

The resultant string is a Unicode string, either a plain string in Py3 or using '`from __future__ import unicode_literals`' in pre Py3.

So we want:

```
i = 404
c = chr_or_unichr (i) # this code is identical for different Python versions

>>> c
'Ɣ'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
try:
    chr = unichr  # Python 2
except NameError:
    pass          # Python 3

i = 404
c = chr(i) # c is now 'Ɣ' regardless of Python version
```

You could also create your own function name if you didn't want to overwrite Python 2's `chr`.

Comment: I'd guess it is working, but you're doing something with the string you get that makes you think it's not. ASCII (and Unicode) character 32 is a space, so doing something like `print(chr(32))` will print what looks like a blank line, but which actually has one invisible space character on it.